# Multiply Values of two dictionaries, while appending the Keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries.
One contain different products and each demand for them.
The other contains a temporal demand distribution values in multiple days.

I need to append the keys of both dictionaries, and multiply the demand by the temporal demand distribution.

Sample Data (real data is much larger):

```
 dict = {'S-NSW-BAC-ENG': 15, 'S-NSW-BAC-FBE': 30}

 temporal_demand_distibution = {-60: 0.001187, -59: 0.001354}
```

The expected output would be something like:

```
resulting_dict = {'S-NSW-BAC-ENG:-60': 0.001187*15, 'S-NSW-BAC-ENG:-59': 0.001354*15, 'S-NSW-BAC-FBE:-60': 30*0.001187, 'S-NSW-BAC-FBE:-59': 30*0.001354}
```

The values would obviously be the result of the multiplication and not the multiplication itself.

I know it's bad to post a question without a sample code, but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Keep in mind that dicts are unordered. This means that you cannot predict which item from ``temporal_demand_distibution`` will get matched with a certain item in ``dict``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a double for loop and combine the keys and values:

```
from pprint import pprint

dict = {'S-NSW-BAC-ENG': 15, 'S-NSW-BAC-FBE': 30}
temporal_demand_distribution = {-60: 0.001187, -59: 0.001354}

result_dict = {}
for key, value in dict.items():
  for key2, value2 in temporal_demand_distribution.items():
    result_dict["{}:{}".format(key, key2)] = value * value2

pprint(result_dict)
```

> ```
> {'S-NSW-BAC-ENG:-59': 0.020309999999999998,
>  'S-NSW-BAC-ENG:-60': 0.017804999999999998,
>  'S-NSW-BAC-FBE:-59': 0.040619999999999996,
>  'S-NSW-BAC-FBE:-60': 0.035609999999999996}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dict = {'S-NSW-BAC-ENG': 15, 'S-NSW-BAC-FBE': 30}
temporal_demand_distibution = {-60: 0.001187, -59: 0.001354}

output = {}
for k, v in dict.items():
    for i, j in temporal_demand_distibution.items():
        output[k + ':' + str(i)] = v * j

print(output)
```

Or a one liner with dictionary comprehension:

```
output = {'%s:%d' % (elem, num): val * decimal for elem, val in dict.items() for num, decimal in temporal_demand_distibution.items()}
```

[Demo here](http://repl.it/qsW).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use dict comprehension, try this:

```
r = {'{}:{}'.format(k1, k2): dict[k1]*temporal_demand_distibution[k2]
     for k1 in dict
     for k2 in temporal_demand_distibution}

print(r)

{'S-NSW-BAC-FBE:-59': 0.040619999999999996, 
'S-NSW-BAC-FBE:-60': 0.035609999999999996, 
'S-NSW-BAC-ENG:-59': 0.020309999999999998, 
'S-NSW-BAC-ENG:-60': 0.017804999999999998}
```